# How can add the next objects to format the page of the document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, tikz-styles, layout

I see some layout in a book that I liked, and I'm trying to make something that looks like it, but I'm unaware of how it should be done.

**Layout intended** (these are two pages separated)

1. First page

[image]

2.Second page

[image]

But I'm stuck, since I can't fix the location of the elements, and the color of the rule, can't get the line of the square to go out or be the same as the fill. And I have no idea about making the example cages (I'm aware there is a bitmap pattern there, it doesn't matter, I wanted the same color to fill all the box).

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{a5d2be}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{color}


\usepackage{float}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}

\copypagestyle{mystyle}{ruled}

\makeheadfootruleprefix{mystyle}{\color{Bittersweet}}{\color{PineGreen}}
\makeheadrule{mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=color1] (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
  \path
    (0, 0) node[below left] {}
    (2, 0) node[below right] {}
    (2, 2) node[above right] {}
    (0, 2) node[above left] {}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\rule[0.5ex]{1\columnwidth}{1pt,color=color1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Don't load `xcolor` twice 2) Is your actual class `article`?  I'm asking it because `\copypagestyle` is a `memoir` command.

Comment: Hum... to be fair I have always used \copypagestyle in this way, so I was thinking this is from the article family. But indeed, the intended classis article.

Comment: `\copypagestyle` gives `Undefined control sequence.` with `article` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope to have understood (almost) all your needs.

I did the `example` box breakable, but if you would like it not to break across pages, just leave out `breakable` option.

I did the `example` title background gray, but you can also add an image, to reproduce the background you like.

Look also at the comments in my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%<--- no more needed since April 2018
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
%\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm}%<--- Are you sure of these dimensions? They don't correspond to the pictures of your posted
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm, nomarginpar}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}<-- Load xcolor only once
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{A5D2BE}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!50!black}

\usepackage{float}

%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
%\usepackage{color}<--- You already loaded xcolor

% Page numenber layout
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\newlength{\myheight}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\setlength{\mywidth}{\paperwidth}%
\addtolength{\mywidth}{-2cm}%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
      \setlength{\myheight}{\paperheight}%
      \addtolength{\myheight}{-2cm}%
      \ifnumodd{\thepage}{%
          \textcolor{mygreen}{\rule[\myheight]{2cm}{2cm}}%
          \addtolength{\myheight}{.7cm}%
          \hspace*{-1cm}%
          \raisebox{\myheight}{\makebox[0pt]{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\thepage}}}%
          \hspace*{1cm}%
      }{%          
          \rule{\mywidth}{0cm}\textcolor{mygreen}{\rule[\myheight]{2cm}{2cm}}%
          \addtolength{\myheight}{.7cm}%
          \hspace*{-1cm}%
          \raisebox{\myheight}{\makebox[0pt]{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\thepage}}}%
          \hspace*{1cm}%
      }%
}
% Section layout
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\color{mygreen}}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{mygreen}}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]

% Caption layout
\usepackage[%
  labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,
  ]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\color{mygreen}\titlerule[2pt]\newline#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[figure]{singlelinecheck=off,format=myformat, name=FIGURE, width=.7\textwidth}

% Example layout
\newcommand{\solution}{\par\vspace{4pt}\textcolor{mygreen}{\textbf{SOLUTION}}\par}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\tcbset{
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    parbox=false,
    extitle/.style={adjusted title={\bfseries EXAMPLE~\thetcbcounter\ifstrempty{#1}{\ignorespaces}{~#1}}}}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{example}[1][]{%
    colback=color1,colframe=lightgray,
    coltitle=mygreen,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    fontupper=\small,
    before skip = 8pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    before upper={\parindent0pt},
    enhanced jigsaw,
    breakable,
    sharp corners,
    extitle={},
    #1
}


\usepackage{lipsum}%<--- for testing purpose only

\begin{document}
\section{Are you sure you want an article?}
From you image it seems you need a book or a report.
\subsection{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]%<--- for testing purpose only
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{}\label{fig:my_label}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]%<--- for testing purpose only
\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]%<--- for testing purpose only
\solution
\lipsum[1]%<--- for testing purpose only
\end{example}
\lipsum[1]%<--- for testing purpose only
\end{document}
```

[image]