# How to produce this Book layout

Tags: book-design

Please, how to produce the design and layout of this book:

formats and colors of sections, sub-sections, top of page, footer ...

[image]

Comment: You should maybe take a look into some packages such as `titlesec`, `fancyhdr` and `geometry`, to name but the most basic ones you probably need to design such a layout.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: I think that when one uses  `titlesec`  for the layout of section titles, it is simpler to use the `titletoc` companion package.

Comment: I suggest the `memoir` class. Read the manual `texdoc memoir`

Comment: @Jasper Habicht, I'm a new user, please there is an example to follow?

Comment: Look here to have an example to start with: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620977/how-can-add-the-next-objects-to-format-the-page-of-the-document

Comment: @CarLaTeX , thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, here is all I could do

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{rufous}{rgb}{0.66, 0.11, 0.03}

%-----------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1] 
{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\textcolor{rufous}{\chaptername\ 
\thechapter.}\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1] 
{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}}
 \fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}

%-----------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\textcolor{rufous}{\csname 
the#1\endcsname}\hspace{0.5em}}

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{-4ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.4ex}{1.3ex \@plus.2ex } 
{\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}}

 \renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
 {-4ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.4ex}
 {1.5ex \@plus.2ex }{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}

 \renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
 {-2ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
 {.2ex \@plus.2ex }
 {\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}  

\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus-.2ex \@minus .2ex}
{.1ex}
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}

%-----------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter{Cinématique}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Référentiel}

\subsection{Lorem ipsum}

\lipsum[5]

\subsubsection{Lorem ipsum}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Thank you all.

[image]

Comment: Was this you expectation?

Comment: You can always accept your own answer.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy yes

Comment: Understandable, have a nice day, happy Latex, get a cup of coffee, and visit https://tug.org

Comment: @VScode_fanboy, thank you dear friend.

Comment: I think that if you had done the research before asking your question, and shown the result, you might well have had more detailed answers. In general, "do this for me" is not appreciated; we are much happier with "I tried this but ...".

Comment: @Peter Wilson I'm sorry.

Comment: @Gallagher No need to be sorry, really just something to consider for your next question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no particular example to follow. You have to make it by yourself to have a look like the given picture.

I suggest you:

1. Know all details like length, width of book pages.
2. Use `memoir` class.
3. Make a rough sketch of your content.
4. Then design manually changing `titlesec`, `fancyhdr` and others to have a look like your given picture.

Answer (score 1):

For each page numbering, I noticed that the even numbered pages have their page numbers to the left and the odd to the right.

You can use the `fancyhdr` package for that and put this in the preamble

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fanypagestyle{newpagestyle}{
\fancyhead[LE, RO]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{newpagestyle}
```

This should set the page numbering in that order.

Answer (score 1):

For coloring section numbers, check here: [Section numbers colored](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252627/section-numbers-colored).

For manipulating footers or headers, just use the `fancyhdr` package. It is a very useful tool.

`\lfoot{Body}` for left footer, `\rfoot{Body}` for right footer, `\cfoot{Body}` for center footer. When you use this in the preamble it works for all, but when you use it in-document, it works for that particular page.

For environment like settings, use the `fancypagestyle` command.

Example:

```
\fancypagestyle{new}{
\fancyfoot[Option]{Body}}
\pagestyle{new}
```

Options can be LE, meaning Left Even, RO for Right Odd, CO, for Center Odd, etc.

It is very easy to manipulate the `fancyhdr` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad to be here.